# How does a service account json file look like?

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

So when creating a service account for an automated system I want to develop for my g-suite, it prompted me to download what I think is the service account credential.
I downloaded a file called client_secret_118180615763713827329.json, that has the following content (will remove sensitive data)

```
{  
   "installed":{  
      "client_id":"clientid",
      "project_id":"projectname",
      "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
   }
}
```

However, I cannot get service account to get authorized. I keep getting the following error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login Required", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Login Required" } }
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: we need to see your code before we can help you address any issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are authenticating your API call by following the guide on this link https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts. The "Login Required" Error message is indicating you that you have not authenticated the user, therefore is not granting you access.